# Raycasting on moving objects

Tags: intersection, raycasting, ogl

I would like to create some mouse interactions on several moving planes and for that, I need to know which planes I'm hovering on. I've implemented the Raycasting method like in your example [here](https://github.com/oframe/ogl/blob/master/examples/raycasting.html) but it seems like I'm hovering all my planes in the center of the canvas, just like if the raycasting method wasn't considering my `position.set()` modifications.

You can see here an example of what I did [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-browser-x3ywv?file=/src/js/canvasSlider.js:5547-5551), I logged the result of the hits array at the end of the `canvasSlider.js` file and all planes are logging when hovering in the center.

Is there a way around that? Or I'm I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are setting the z scale to 0.

```
plane.scale.set(1, size.height/size.width, 0);
```

Replace the 0 with a 1 to enable the hit tests to function.

Another issue I noticed was that your mouse values are relative to the screen and not the canvas. As the canvas is on a scrolling page it may not be taking up the full screen at all times.